# How to know if user who signed in with Google is a new user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to know if the user who has just signed in with Google is a new user, so I can take an action needed for new users in my app.
I heard about this method `isNewUser()`   , but I'm actually not familiar with abstract methods and I don't know exactly how I can use it in my situation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#isNewUser()

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        // TAKE ACTION IF IT IS A NEW USER.
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.authentication_failed,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really familiar with Firebase, but as it is a part of Google Play Services, it's likely that you get a class that overrides it right away (as in you don't have to override it). Just call the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off defining for yourself what it means to be a "new user", and using a database to reflect that.  For example, if a user doesn't have any data in your database keyed by their UID, you could make the assumption that they are new.  Then you update the database to reflect the fact that they are no longer new.

Comment: Yep, thanks Doug, that's what I'm doing instead. But I think the method isNewUser() would be perfect if I knew how to use it properly :)

Comment: Don't assume that it's perfect.  It may not actually reflect what you want to do in your app.  For example, the user could be signing in for the first time, but fail to complete some first-time tasks.  In that case you don't want to depend on isNewUser to help them complete their tasks the next time they log in - you want to have your own record of what happened.

Comment: Well thought! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a better way to do this now.
To check if a user is new or existing after sign in, use `isNewUser`: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#isNewUser()
which is on `AdditionalUserInfo`, available on `AuthResult` when the task resolves.

Comment: Won't work, if you sign in the user anonymously. Will always return false when connecting the profiles.

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with the above question.The above question does not use anonymous + linking flow.

Comment: It has everything to do with the question. And especially with your answer. Further readers will use your answer and are not aware that it won't work if they use anon signIn, which is common. So worth mentioning. 
Do not feel personally attacked.

Comment: I don't care about being attacked. I care about accuracy and facts. The question is pretty clear above. There is no mention of anonymous users.

Comment: I still think it is worth mentioning that a method, although the doc does not imply it, won't work in some circumstances.